# Data management with Core Data right way to do between multiple controllers

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I'm having problems with the way things should work. I'm constantly having te figure out how to manage some data in some situations. Example:
I'm using core data and initialize it in my first `View Controller` in an array with a `NSFetchRequest`.

```
[Trip]() -> (Trip: beginDate:Date, endDate:Date, isBookmark:Bool, etc)
```

I have a Tableview where I only want to let the users see the trips that have a `isBookmark: false`, I have an other View Controller where I would only let the `isBookmark: true` see.

**Problems I'm having now:**

- The moment the user creates a new trip, its default the current bookmarked trip. I can't reach all my Trip objects from the other view controller, before I was using a delegate function between my `View Controllers`, this is not possible anymore because I've added a `TabBarController`.
- I'm creating a new `Trip(context: context)` when the user want to add a new trip. Problem now with the `TabBarController` is that the Core Data context that it's already showing a null element in my TableView even if I didn't call the `save() context` yet.
- I tought maybe for the bookmarks to create a new Core Data Entity in general like `"Trips with 2 atributes (notSelectedTrips, selectedTrip)"` and that I move the Trips itself between these two. Is this a good idea or can I do it in an other way?

So yeah, I'm a bit stuck. If anyone could show me the way to go this would be great!

Comment: Not sure I understand all your issues but try not to instantiate a Trip object until it's time to save it or make sure you delete it if the user leaves the create new view without saving it.

Comment: It’s not very clear what are you trying to achieve: is it a detail view that shall get injected with a managed object represented in core data context? If so you’ll just inject such object to the view controller and when such controller gets dismissed you’d save the context is in to persist the changes made to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should show a little bit more code to get a better idea where you are doing something wrong.

I assume you are using the same context for editing that you are showing the data from in your tableview, which you should not do.

You should be using a backgroundcontext for saving the changes, while a NSFetchedResultsController observes the changes on the viewContext. Once the backgroundContext saves back, the other context will show it.
Check out the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/using_core_data_in_the_background

Comment: Thanks for the response! I think I'm doing it wrong, I'm using context to create my object in "Adding Trips" and passing along views that 1 object. I think I should delete that, only create a new Trip object for context on pressing the save.

Comment: Correct, do not do that. Create your object in a backgroundContext and save it. Fetch the object again in the other viewContext.